# Passed parameters/variables aren't correct

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, chemistry

While practicing OOP with inheritance in my second class I have problems adding my parameters, as you can see I have: `(self, name, tred, PM, PM2, ra, ra2)`. But when run the program it tells me that I can not multiply `Nonetype`, I print them to see what's wrong and i get that some of the parameters are incorrect.

The first class works fine (`Atomic_d`), I just need to understand how does it work the variables in the second class: `Molecular_d`

How can I fix this?

[This is the complete code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4gsX.png)

```
import math
class Atomic_d():
    def __init__(self,name="",red="",PM=None,ra=None):
        self.name = name
        self.red = red
        self.PM = PM
        self.ra = ra

    def density(self):
        redes = {"BCC":2,"FCC":4,"HCP":6}
        self.red = self.red.upper()
        nred = redes.get(self.red)
        nav = round(6.022*(10**23),3)

        if nred == 2:
            a = (4*(self.ra))/((3)**0.5)
        elif nred == 4:
            a = (4*(self.ra))/((2)**0.5)
        else:
            per = round(12 * self.ra,3)
            hipoc = round((2*self.ra)**2,3)
            basec = round(self.ra**2,3)
            apo = round(math.sqrt(hipoc - basec),3)
            a = round((per * apo / 2),3)

        if nred == 2 or nred == 4:
            vol = a**3
        elif nred == 6:
            vol = round(a * 3.266 * self.ra,3)
        
        density = round((((nred*self.PM)/(nav*vol))*10**21),3)
        return "{} : {} g/cc".format(self.name,density)

class Molecular_d(Atomic_d):
    def __init__(self,name="",tred="",PM=None,ra=None,PM2=None,ra2=None):
        super().__init__(name,PM,ra)
        self.PM2 = PM2
        self.ra2 = ra2
        self.tred = tred
    
    def density(self):
        tredes = {"NACL":8}
        self.tred = self.tred.upper()
        nred = tredes.get(self.tred)
        nav = round(6.022*(10**23),3)
    
        if nred == 8:
            l = round(((2*self.ra)*(2*self.ra2)),3)
            vol = l**3
        
        density = ((8*(self.PM + self.PM2))/(nav*vol))
        return "{}: {} g/cc".format(self.name,density)
```

[This is the error that happens when I try to debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQVvb.png)
I print every variable to see what is the problem

```
    print("Hi I'm name",self.name)
    print("Hi I'm ra",self.ra)
    print("Hi I'm ra2",self.ra2)
    print("Hi I'm PM",self.PM)
    print("Hi I'm PM2",self.PM2)

Hi I'm name Ox de magnesio
Hi I'm ra None
Hi I'm ra2 0.14
Hi I'm PM 16.0
Hi I'm PM2 0.072
```

Traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-bb7a69690a34> in <module>
      1 magnesium_ox = Molecular_d("Ox de magnesio","NaCl",24.31,16.0,0.072,0.14)
      2 
----> 3 magnesium_ox.density()

<ipython-input-19-064f60b8cfce> in density(self)
     52 
     53         if nred == 8:
---> 54             l = round(((2*self.ra)*(2*self.ra2)),3)
     55             vol = l**3
     56 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: In `super().__init__(name,PM,ra)`, you aren't passing `red`, which means that `ra` at the end isn't being filled. In a case like this, it doesn't make much sense to have `=None` defaults, since the object is "invalid" if any of the data is missed. Without the defaults, you would have gotten an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make the call to super()_init(), you leave out the `red` argument.  Python assumes that the three arguments you are passing are `name`, `red`, and `pa`, even though that's seems not to be what you intended.

When you don't attach parameter= to an argument, Python assumes you are giving them from left to right.  You need to write:

```
super().__init__(name=name, PM=PM, ra=ra)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using keyword arguments if you are not going to put them same order as the class. Try changing the `Molecular_d` to this below:

```
class Molecular_d(Atomic_d):
    def __init__(self,name="",tred="",PM=None,ra=None,PM2=None,ra2=None):
        super().__init__(name=name,PM=PM,ra=ra)
        self.PM2 = PM2
        self.ra2 = ra2
        self.tred = tred
    
    def density(self):
        tredes = {"NACL":8}
        self.tred = self.tred.upper()
        nred = tredes.get(self.tred)
        nav = round(6.022*(10**23),3)
        
        if nred == 8:
            l = round(((2*self.ra)*(2*self.ra2)),3)
            vol = l**3
        else: 
            vol = 10
        
        density = ((8*(self.PM + self.PM2))/(nav*vol))
        return "{}: {} g/cc".format(self.name,density)

mag =  Molecular_d(name="a", tred="as", PM=1.1, ra=0.2, PM2=2.3, ra2=40.1)

result = mag.density()
print(result)
<< 'a: 4.5167718365991366e-24 g/cc'
```

I added in a default value of vol, because i'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

You have that:

```py
class Atomic_d():
    def __init__(self,name="",red="",PM=None,ra=None):
```

But, initialization is:

```py
class Molecular_d(Atomic_d):
    def __init__(self,name="",tred="",PM=None,ra=None,PM2=None,ra2=None):
        super().__init__(name,PM,ra)
```

it:

```
super().__init__(name,PM,ra)
```

goes to:

```
def __init__(self,name="",red="",PM=None,ra=None):
```

as

```
__init__(self,name=name,red=PM,PM=ra,ra=None):
```

So, `ra` param was not initialised.